# I need to save a df to excel. First column has 15 digits so it is taking as scientific number; how to avoid that

Tags: python, excel, csv, export-to-excel

I have a to save a file to_excel
But the fist column has 15 digits in it and in Excel is showing as 31100000+13 something in want this to show as number itself how do I do that.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test1.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#'})
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30, format1)
writer.save()
```

I tried this code problem is it's adding index and also it's not helping with the scientific number also
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAqGo.jpg)
This is the output image and i want to change the RMA it should display all the number instead scientific number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify:

```
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
```

by

```
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1', index=False)
```

This will remove index.